# When setting padding for a div with display:table-cell, it changes padding of a neighbour div with the same display

Tags: html, padding, css-tables

I've created a container `<div id="container">` for my content, which in return has a simple `<div id="leftbar">` and `<div id="content">` for the main text of the page.

I've made the `<div id="container">` as a `display:table` in styles, and both `<div id="leftbar">` and `<div id="content">` as `display:table-cell`.

The problem I'm having now is, whenever I try to change `padding` on the `<div id="content">`, it affects padding in `<div id="leftbar">` for some reason. And it applies only for the top `padding`.
How can I resolve this, and better yet, why is this happening? Is it because of the table structure?

Providing with code, and jsfiddle. In jsfiddle change the last `padding` line in CSS to see how it shifts everything in the left bar.

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/krQBHIx.jpg" width="690" height="100"/></div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="leftbar">
            <ul>
                <p class="heading">Navigation</p>
                <li><a href="#">Main</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lessons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>

            <p class="heading" style="background: #bb0;">Subscribe</p>
            <form action="subscribe.php" method="POST" name="form1">
                Subscribe to our RSS feed and get all the fresh news and articles directly in your mail box!<br /><br />
                <label><p>Enter your name:</p><input type="text"/></label>
                <label><p>Enter your e-mail:</p><input type="text"/></label>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send!"/>
            </form>                          
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. 
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div id="footer"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/2GzQuoo.jpg" width="690" height="18"/></div>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
/* Styles */

*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
    font: 14px Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

*:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
 }

a
{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

body
{
    background: #606B79;
}

p
{
    font: 14px Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#wrapper
{
    width: 690px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

#header img
{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}

#footer img
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-top: none;
    display: block;
}

#container
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    background: #fff;
}

#leftbar
{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 184px;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
}

#leftbar ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 15px;    
}

.heading
{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #a22;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;    
}

#leftbar ul li
{
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-bottom: none;  
}

#leftbar ul li:last-child
{
    border: 1px solid gray;    
}

#leftbar a
{
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 4px;
}

#leftbar a:hover
{
    background: #ccc;
}

#leftbar form
{
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
}

#leftbar form input
{
    width: 149px;
    margin: 3px 0;
}

#leftbar form input[type="submit"]
{
    height: 25px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin-top: 20px; 
}

#content
{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 506px;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 25px;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Qtpj/

Help me, please?

Comment: because the width of your table div is 100%, your table-cell div widths are being calculated as a ratio of the given width and padding, so changing one cell will alter that ratio making both cells change.  If you want to get around this, you could put a div inside the table-cell div and then add the padding to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your CSS styles. Don use display:table for aligning elements if you can use "float"
Here is your code

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden
}
#content {
    float:right;
    width:506px;
    padding:25px;
}
#leftbar {
    width:184px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: why not use `display:table` for aligning elements?

Comment: I used `float` before, but thought this could benefit in setting `div` to the same height. Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: @Arno I understand you need same height there to get white bg? But you can set it to the #container

Answer (score 3):

The content in your #leftbar div is aligned to the baseline. To fix your current html/css change the following:

```
#leftbar
{
    vertical-align: top;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 184px;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

BUT! You really should be using another method for this. Displaying non-table elements as tables can have its issues, and isn't needed anymore.

Start learning about flexbox [the latest and greatest in web layout] - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and use floats as a fallback [see @AlexPrinceton's answer].

Comment: Just thought using it as table could be easier to fix same height issue. Why is it that worse than using float?

Comment: Mainly because IE6/7 don't support it. True, soon we wont need to support them - but the float way is just as easy [easier even?] and has solid support.

Comment: Flexbox is really early to use now - maybe when it will be support for major browsers

Comment: edit: you can write fallbacks for flexbox to support older browsers, but perhaps this isnt the time to be discussing such methods. Stick with @AlexPrinceton's method :)